# Filtering using viewsets in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Please consider these three models:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    synopsis = models.TextField()

class TimeTable(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

class Show(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey(TimeTable)
    time = models.TimeField(choices=CHOICE_TIME)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('day', 'time')
```

And each of them has their serializers:

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    movie_id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True, source="id")

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = '__all__'    

class TimeTableSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TimeTable
        fields = '__all__'


class ShowSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Show
        fields = '__all__'
```

And their routers

```
router.register(r'movie-list', views.MovieViewSet)
router.register(r'time-table', views.TimeTableViewSet)
router.register(r'show-list', views.ShowViewSet)
```

Now I would like to get all the TimeTable objects (i.e. date list) by filtering all the Show objects by a specific movie object. This code seems to be the working and getting the list like I want it

```
m = Movie.objects.get(id=request_id)
TimeTable.objects.filter(show__movie=m).distinct()
```

But I have no clue how to use this in django rest framework? I tried doing this way (which I am  pretty sure its wrong), and I am getting error:

views.py:

```
class DateListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, movie_id):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id)
    queryset = TimeTable.objects.filter(show__movie=movie).distinct()
    serializer_class = TimeTableSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
router.register(r'date-list/(?P<movie_id>.+)/', views.DateListViewSet)
```

error:

> class DateListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, movie_id):
>   NameError: name 'movie_id' is not defined

How can I filter using viewsets in django rest framework? Or if there is any other prefered way than please list it out. Thank you.

Comment: @一切都是空虚 Sorry, that was a typo. Updated correctly.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`ModelViewSet` by design assumes that you want to implement a CRUD(create, update, delete)
There is also a `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` which implements only the `GET` method to read only endpoints.
For `Movie` and `Show` models, a `ModelViewSet` or `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` is a good choice whether you want implement CRUD or not.
But a separate `ViewSet` for a related query of a `TimeTable` which describes a `Movie` model's schedule doesn't looks so good.
A better approach would be to put that endpoint to a `MovieViewSet` directly. DRF provided it by `@detail_route` and `@list_route` decorators.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewset):

    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    @detail_route()
    def date_list(self, request, pk=None):
        movie = self.get_object() # retrieve an object by pk provided
        schedule = TimeTable.objects.filter(show__movie=movie).distinct()
        schedule_json = TimeTableSerializer(schedule, many=True)
        return Response(schedule_json.data)
```

This endpoint will be available by a `movie-list/:id/date_list` url
[Docs about extra routes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions)

Comment: I know this is an old post(might be useful for someone, as have been for me today), but due to the recent updates of DRF 3.9 the `@detail_route()` has been replaced. The decorator has been replaced with `action` so in this case it would be `@action(detail=True)` according to the DRF announcements, which can be found here: [Django Rest framework 3.9 announcements](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/#action-decorator-replaces-list_route-and-detail_route)

Answer (score 10):

Register your route as

```
router.register(r'date-list', views.DateListViewSet)
```

now change your viewset as shown below,

```
class DateListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TimeTable.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimeTableSerializer
    lookup_field = 'movie_id'

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        movie_id = kwargs.get('movie_id', None)
        movie = Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id)
        self.queryset = TimeTable.objects.filter(show__movie=movie).distinct()
        return super(DateListViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Use a retrieve method, which will match any GET requests to endpoint **`/date-list/<id>/`**.

**Advantage is that you don't have to explicitly handle the serialization and returning response** you make ViewSet to do that hard part. We are only updating the queryset to be serialized and rest framework does the rest.

Since ModelViewSet is implemented as,

```
class ModelViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   GenericViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides default `create()`, `retrieve()`, `update()`,
    `partial_update()`, `destroy()` and `list()` actions.
    """
    pass
```

Its implementation includes the following methods (HTTP verb and endpoint on bracket)

- **`list()` (GET `/date-list/`)**
- **`create()`(POST `/date-list/`)**
- **`retrieve()`(GET `date-list/<id>/`)**
- **`update()` (PUT `/date-list/<id>/`)**
- **`partial_update()` (PATCH, `/date-list/<id>/`**
- **`destroy()` (DELETE `/date-list/<id>/`)**

If you want only to implement the `retrieve()` (**GET requests to endpoint `date-list/<id>/`**), you can do this instead of a `ModelViewSet),

```
from rest_framework import mixins, views

class DateListViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = TimeTable.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimeTableSerializer
    lookup_field = 'movie_id'

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        movie_id = kwargs.get('movie_id', None)
        movie = Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id)
        self.queryset = TimeTable.objects.filter(show__movie=movie).distinct()
        return super(DateListViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 9):

The error

> class DateListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, movie_id): NameError: name 'movie_id' is not defined

happens because `movie_id` is being passed as parent class of DataListViewSet and not as parameter as you imagined

This example in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url) should be what you are looking for.

Adjust your URL:

```
url(r'date-list/(?P<movie_id>.+)/', views.DateListView.as_view())
```

Adjust your Model:

```
class Show(models.Model):
   day = models.ForeignKey(TimeTable, related_name='show')
   time = models.TimeField(choices=CHOICE_TIME)
   movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('day', 'time')
```

Your view would look like this:

```
class DateListView(generics.ListAPIView):
     serializer_class = TimeTableSerializer

     def get_queryset(self):

         movie = Movie.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['movie_id'])

         return TimeTable.objects.filter(show__movie=movie).distinct()
```

Another way to do it would be:

Adjust your URL:

```
router.register(r'date-list', views.DateListViewSet)
```

Adjust your Model:

```
class Show(models.Model):
   day = models.ForeignKey(TimeTable, related_name='show')
   time = models.TimeField(choices=CHOICE_TIME)
   movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('day', 'time')
```

Your view would look like this:

```
class DateListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     serializer_class = TimeTableSerializer
     queryset = TimeTable.objects.all()
     filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
     filter_fields = ('show__movie_id')
```

Which will allow you to make requests such as:

```
http://example.com/api/date-list?show__movie_id=1
```

See [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)

Comment: I think it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 4):

Ivan Semochkin has the correct answer but the detail decorator is deprecated. It was replaced by the [action decorator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#routing-additional-http-methods-for-extra-actions).

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action

class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewset):

   @action(detail=True)
   def date_list(self, request, pk=None):
       movie = self.get_object() # retrieve an object by pk provided
       schedule = TimeTable.objects.filter(show__movie=movie).distinct()
       schedule_json = TimeTableSerializer(schedule, many=True)
       return Response(schedule_json.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve @all-is-vanity answer, you can explicitly use `movie_id` as a parameter in the `retrieve` function since you are overriding the `lookup_field` class property:

```
def retrieve(self, request, movie_id=None):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id)
    self.queryset = TimeTable.objects.filter(show__movie=movie).distinct()
    return super(DateListViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You can also call `self.get_object()` to get the object:

```
def retrieve(self, request, movie_id=None):
    movie = self.get_object()
    self.queryset = TimeTable.objects.filter(show__movie=movie).distinct()
    return super(DateListViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```